# JNLP port is missing from Configure Global Security in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jnlp, jenkins-agent

I'm creating a windows agent in Jenkins and for that, I need to use the Java Web Start as a launch method in agent configuration.
I'm aware that to view this option in agent configuration, we need to change the setting in Manage Jenkins>Configure global security>Agents>TCP JNLP AGents to Random from disabled.

But in my case, I'm not able to see the JNLP port agent, the option visible is "TCP port for inbound agents" instead of "TCP port for JNLP agents".

I've installed JDK in Manage Jenkins>Global tool Configuration, but after this as well it's not giving an option for JNLP agents.

Can someone please help with this, where I can view the "TCP port for JNLP agents" option under Jenkins>Configure global security>Agents

Comment: did you enabled security?

Answer (score 7):

The 'TCP port for JNLP agents' setting seems to be not available anymore in the 'Configure Global Security' settings. Instead of that modify your agent's settings and set Launch method as 'Launch agent by connecting it to master'. It works similarly to the option that you are looking for:

[image: Launch method screenshot]

Comment: Links are great, but it would be even more helpful if you could summarize a possible way to correct the problem outlined in the question.

Comment: @ShanteshwarInde actually it answers the question

Answer (score 5):

Agents communicate through each other over TCP.In my case i couldnt find "TCP port for JNLP agents".Solution for it is,before creating an agent ,go to Configure global security ->section labeled "Agents" and the line that says "TCP port for inbound agents".  Insert a valid port value for the TCP port for inbound agents.  Apply that change.

Then goto Configure Jenkins -> Manage Nodes -> create new node or configure node
Choose the setting  "Launch agent by connecting it to the controller" under Launch Method.

The phrasing has been improved significantly in the user interface by removing the references to "JNLP".  The key difference between the agent protocols is not the underlying transport, but rather which end initiates the connection.  The agent launch method that was formerly called "JNLP" is a launch method that initiates the agent connection from the agent to the master.  The launch method called "ssh" initiates the connection from the master to the agent.

Answer (score 0):

TCP port for inbound agents
Set Random there. and save
[Set Random port](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFFaJ.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).